# Separate The dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu (Relocate/Reinstall Grub)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I have a working dual OS installation of Windows (GPT SSD /dev/sdb) and Ubuntu (MBR HDD /dev/sda). The problem is that part of the grub lies in /dev/sdb which means if this drive is erased/disconnected (which I intend to do) am gonna lose my Ubuntu Installation forever.

When /dev/sdb is unplugged from the motherboard, I get `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found` after which I get the grub rescue prompt when I boot from the HDD (/dev/sda).

I tried to use the existing installation of Ubuntu to re-install the grub on /dev/sda using
`grub-install /dev/sda` or `grub-install --skip-fs-probe /dev/sda` then `update-grub` the installation finishes without errors but still I am unable to boot from /dev/sdb without /dev/sda being connected.

Any idea how to make /dev/sda boot without /dev/sdb?

Comment: It sounds like you have an UEFI install of Ubuntu on an MBR drive. But an UEFI boot loader on the Windows drive. And then you may have installed a BIOS boot version of grub to Ubuntu drive, which then does not boot the UEFI install? Best to only use gpt and have ESP on every drive. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Boot-info summary report [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Xxtr4GVrMW/). yes I believe you are right. btw, I already have tried the auto fix and it did nothing just reinstalled everything again. What are my available options so far? Do I need to format /dev/sdb/ to make it GPT instead of MBR? as I don't have an ESP partition in it. Also Is it possible for Ubuntu to boot in BIOS MBR mode?

Comment: Another question, If I format my C: (Windows) partition on /dev/sda leaving the ESP intact, my boot would still work, right?

Comment: Your NVMe and sdb drives are gpt, sda is MBR. You show grub in MBR of sda to boot install in sda6 in BIOS mode. But have both Windows & Ubuntu in ESP on sdb2 for UEFI boot. Your fstab has the mount of the ESP, so Ubuntu on MBR drive is booting in UEFI mode from ESP on sdb2. Not sure if grub in MBR still works or not. But better to use gpt with UEFI, but normal conversion will erase drive. Do you have good backups? Best would be ESP, Windows & Ubuntu /(root) on NVMe drive and sda & sdb as gpt data partitions and/or /home.

Comment: Turns out that the auto repair had exchanged the names of my drives, so I edited the the original question. Thanks for the Assist. If I delete the C: Partition where Windows is installed on /dev/sdb leaving ESP partition untouched I would still be able to boot, right?

Comment: You should be able to boot Ubuntu, not sure about Windows. And script does not show BCD. Best to have ESP for Windows on Windows gpt partitioned drive. Best to always have good backups, so you can easily restore something.